# Magento new order email body is coming as blank

Tags: email, magento

I am sending the new order email to the customer after saving the order in the database table. The order is complete in the sales section in the admin but the order email body is blank as i received the email but the email subject is OK. Can anyone help me what is going wrong. i am using the Magento 1.7.0.2 version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

Goto `Admin -> System -> Transactional Emails`

Edit or add a new transaction email for 'order email' and 'order email guest'

Then

Go to `Admin -> System -> Config -> Sales Emails` and assign the right templates

Comment: i tried this but not working. I am getting blank email body still.

Comment: Yes ... no log was coming too. Can you please help me. I have wasted 6 hours in this. Thanks

Comment: Order email is not working. Email subject is OK but the body is blank.

Comment: Yes. I have defined in the Admin -> system -> Transactional Email than load default template i have selected is "New order" and than in admin -> System -> Config -> Sales Emails i have assigned that

Comment: Try creating a new `transactional email` for guest... then assign it in `sales emails` and then create a new order using guest checkout (not from admin)

Comment: I tried it many times but still the email body is blank. Please help. I have a custom plugin in which i want to send the new order email once the order placed. Order is being placed successfully in the sales section.

Comment: What does this 'custom plugin' does? Try disable it to see if your email work.

Comment: The email is coming fine via placing order on the web but not in my custom module.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24977/discussion-between-tinkesh-and-r-s)

Comment: Add the config.xml file for your custom module above

Comment: Sir can you tell me that why i am getting the exception "No date part in ''" while saving new order. How to resolve this?Thanks

Comment: Add your config.xml to your question